# Rotationally invariant spin states

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Other than the singlet state which is invariant under rotations under all three axes, what are the other known SU(2) invariant states? I think full states are also invariant but references to articles or books are welcome.

Comment: What is your definition of "invariant" that it does not coincide with your definition of "singlet"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind You are funny. Singlet is not the only invariant state. It is the only invariant in 3 dimensions. 00 + 11 is invariant in 2 d. What is your definition of plumage that you are such a peacock?

Comment: I was not trying to be funny. I literally define a "singlet state" as one that is invariant under rotations (or $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, whichever diction to prefer), or, in more mathematical terms, a singlet is the trivial representation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "full states" but by definition a state $\vert \psi\rangle$ is invariant if $R\vert\psi\rangle=\vert \psi\rangle$ for an arbitrary $R\in$SU(2).  Since this implies
$$
R'\circ R\vert\psi\rangle = \vert\psi\rangle
$$
for every $R', R\in$SU(2), $\vert\psi\rangle$ spans a 1-dimensional representation of SU(2).  There is only one 1-dimensional representation: it is the $J=0$ (i.e. singlet) representation.